# How to add the sum of values onto the column labels on excel?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I found an excel file that has the sum of all the values on the column labels on a Pivot Table. How is this done?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add more than one field to the values section, a Values field is place in the column labels to allow you to move the values above or below additional column labels. You can also move that values label to the row labels.